# Растрирование (сохранение в JPG, PDF) кэшированной страницы

Tags: php, wordpress

На определённом этапе работы сайт выдаёт пользователю HTML код с таблицей и набором SVG файлов. Далее этот код открывается в новой вкладке. Но это крайне неудобно, так как, к примеру, chrome не позволяет правильно распечатать получившийся набор символов. И пользователям приходиться сохранять методом тыка по клавише PRINTSCREEN и далее уже распечатывать результат. Сайт на WordPress vibr.efimchenko.ru

Возможно, существуют какие-то библиотеки для растрирования результата?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно, существуют. Я использовал [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf).

Comment: К сожалению не работает с SVG. Я пробовал связку canvg + html2canvas но последний смещает внутреннее изображение background, что не допустимо.